# How to Convert byte array to hexString in java?

Tags: java

I have byte array that consist of hex values like `CA ,FA,21,33`

But I want to list them in `JList` as a single element `CAFA2133`.
In order to list them in JList I think I need to convert it to `string`.
So any recommendation?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to look at [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) specifications.

e.g.

`String.format("%02x", byteValue);`

Iterate through the array and append each `String.format()` result to a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Nice and simple. No need for me to sift through the wall of text on the other duplicate question and answers :)

Comment: it works, but it takes about 3 times longer than the method below based on byte operations

Comment: Interesting. Can you link to the specific answer below ?

Answer (score 55):

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] in) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : in) {
        builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    final char[] hexArray = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/12860)

Comment: Looks like copy and paste from the duplicate question. You should at least mention the source from where you copied it.

Comment: he does have the source link as a part of the answer

Comment: @MrSmith42: I've put the source in bold for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This method should do that for you..pass in the byte array as a parameter to return the hex string...

```
private static String convertToHexString(byte[] data) {
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
    int two_halfs = 0;
    do {
        if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9))
            buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
        else
            buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
        } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
    }
return buf.toString();
}
```

hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Integer.toStringint i, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) to convert each of your numbers into a string in hexadecimal, and then concatenate them together. Now you just have to get your bytes into an int.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `Integer`'s [`toHexString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29).
Converting your `byte` to `int` and then obtaining the resulting String should do the trick.
Of course, you would have to concatenate the Strings with a `StringBuilder` then.

Answer (score 0):

If this array is 4 bytes long, you could probably concatenate bytes and make use of Integer.toString(int, int) method.

```
byte[] array = /* initialization */;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0, l = Math.min(array.length, 4); i < l; i++) {
    x <<= 8;
    x |= (array[i] & 0xFF);
}
String hex = Integer.toString(x, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NumUtil
{   private static HashMap<Byte,char[]>byteToHex=new HashMap<Byte, char[]>();
    static
    {   for(int i=0;i<16;++i)
            byteToHex.put((byte)i, new char[]{'0',Integer.toHexString(i).charAt(0)});
        for(int i=16;i<256;++i)
            byteToHex.put((byte)i, Integer.toHexString(i).toCharArray());
    }
    public static String toHexString(byte[]bytes)
    {   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(bytes.length*2);
        for(byte b:bytes)
            stringBuilder.append(byteToHex.get(b));
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```