# How to print the response body using JSR223 sampler with MQ testing in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I got an opportunity to work on IBM MQ testing recently. Since, i am new to this testing. i have referred multiple blogs in Stackoverflow to prepare our code. Currently i am referring following blog code to inject my XML payloads + Rfh2 header values([How to send message with RFH2 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321214/how-to-send-message-with-rfh2-format)). Actually i am able to inject the request but i cannot see any response in listener.

I have tried adding below code snippet, but i am getting "com.ibm.mq.MQMessage@1d3ef24d" as output.

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(message.toString())
SampleResult.setDataType( org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT )
SampleResult.setLatency( stop.toEpochMilli() - start.toEpochMilli() )
```

We require message id, put time, put date details in the response. Could someone please help how to extract these values.

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQAsyncStatus
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants
import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQRFH2

def mqProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>()
mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, 'xxxxxxxxx')
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414)
mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, 'XXXXXXXXX')

def qManager = 'QM1'
def queueName = 'DEV.QUEUE.1'


def qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, mqProps)
def openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
def queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions)

def pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions()
pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE
def message = new MQMessage()
message.format = CMQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2
def rfh2 = new MQRFH2()
rfh2.setEncoding(CMQC.MQENC_NATIVE)
rfh2.setCodedCharSetId(CMQC.MQCCSI_INHERIT)
rfh2.setFormat(CMQC.MQFMT_STRING)
rfh2.setNameValueCCSID(1208)
rfh2.setFieldValue('usr', 'Test', 'Country')

rfh2.write(message)

message.writeString('''${request_payload}''')

queue.put(message, pmo)
queue.close()
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to print the MQMessage object using System.out.println method. You will need to use messageId, putDateTime properties of MQMessage get the details. Please note messageId is a byte array.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Shashi. Yeah i need to know how to print that messageId.

Comment: MessageId is byte array. You will need to convert the every byte in the array to hexadecimal string before printing. Some sample here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429257/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-hexstring-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display generated message as the response data of the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you need to do something like:

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(message.readUTF(), 'UTF-8')
```

More information:

- [SampleResult.setResponseData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [MQMessage.readUTF()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMessage.html#readUTF__)
- [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dmitri T. I am getting EOF file error when i use above code line..

Comment: You are using writeString method to write the payload when sending. For reading you will need to use readString method.

Comment: Oh let me check with readString method. Thanks for your response @Shashi